# How to find variable from Math.Round statement

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, calculation

We have a calculation in code that calculates some adjusted value like this

```
a = Math.Round(b, 3) + Math.Round(b * c1, 3) + Math.Round(b * c2, 3);
```

The problem is that now I need to do reversed calculation. I have values for `a`,`c1`& `c2` and need to find value of `b`. Is that possible?

Comment: With `Math.Round()`? To get back the **exact** value?

Comment: Short answer, no. Rounding loses information by definition. At best you can maybe narrow it down to a range of values.

Comment: There are multiple values of `b` that would result in the same value of `a`, so obviously you can only produce one of them in the reverse.

Comment: @juharr - Any of these values should be enough for my case.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I don't want to get exact value. Just any value which will produce correct result when put in the original formula.

Comment: @Gab in that case it's just `b = a / (1 + c1 + c2);`

Comment: @juharr If you will put this in the original formula, you will not get the same "a".

Comment: @Gab can you give an example of the values of `c1`, `c2`, and `a` where it wouldn't?

Comment: For example c1 = 0.0125, c2 = 0.0517,a = 0.155. But I need some working solution for all possible values.

Comment: Try `(int)((1000) * (a/(1+c1+c2)))/1000.0` as that will truncate the values past 3 digits.  Though I believe you'll be able to find values that even this wouldn't work for.

Comment: @juharr - No, unfortunately it still produces different values during back-calculation (( But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Your back calculation is going to be off due to all the rounding errors you are introducing. Is there a reason you round _every term_ rather than just round the result anyway? Why not `Math.Round(b + b * c1 + b * c2, 3);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming b, c1 and c2 are all positive, you have an increasing function so you can binary search over it to find b. There may exist a formula to get b directly, but this should work fast enough as well. Here is a python example:

```
c1 = 0.0125
c2 = 0.0517
a = 0.155

def op(b, c1, c2):
    return round(b, 3) + round(b * c1, 3) + round(b * c2, 3) 

minb = 0
maxb = a

while (minb + 0.00001 < maxb):
    b = (minb + maxb) / 2
    estimate = op(b, c1, c2)

    if estimate > a:
        maxb = b
    elif estimate < a:
        minb = b
    else:
        break

print(b, op(b, c1, c2))
```

Comment: I tested with several values, looks like this works! Thanks!